# Concavity of ths function (two variables)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have to find the values of $\lambda$ (real) for which $f(x, y) = -(x-y)^4 + \lambda x^{2/3}$ is concave.

**Attempts**

I know that $(x-y)^4$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^2$ hence $-(x-y)^4$ is concave. Since sum of concave functions is concave, then I must find $\lambda$ for which $x^{2/3}$ is concave.

I know that in $\mathbb{R}$, $x^{2/3}$ is concave, hence it's concave in $\mathbb{R}^{2+}$ too.

So I would say that for $\lambda \geq 0$, $f(x, y)$ is concave in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Yet I tried to plot the whole function for $\lambda = -2$ and it looks like concave too...

What am I missing?

**ADD**

Can I say that, studying the function alont $y \to 0$, I can reduce the problem to the study of

$$f(x, 0) = -x^4 + \lambda x^{2/3}$$

and by observing that for $\lambda < 0$, the function is convex, hence not concave in $\mathbb{R}^{2+}$?

Comment: How are you defining $x^{2/3}$ for negative $x$?

Comment: @kimchilover Ops, sorry, I meant $\mathbb{R}^{2+}$, going to edit.

Answer (score 0):

We know that a function f, supposed differentiable, is concave if and only if its hessian matrix $H_{f}(x,y)$ is negative semi-definite for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2+}$. Deriving, we get that
$$
H_{f}(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{9}\lambda x^{-4/3}-12(x-y)^2 & 12(x-y)^2 \\
12(x-y)^2 & -12(x-y)^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And then what's left is to determine $\lambda$ such that this matrix is negative semi-definite.

Comment: So can I just check for when the determinant is positive, and the first pivot is negative?

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient